# Contacts App crashes when switching between Dialer to Call log

Tags: android, crash, runtime, contacts

I've altered the contact app so that in Dialer the soft keypad always stays and it hides when other tab activity resumes, We've given different look for the contacts app, but when using the same, a crash occurs when we rapidly change from dialer to call log. And the App crashes without the standard crash dialog.

I have copied the log and the error seems to be happening in a deeper section..

```
 01-01 06:25:37.401: DEBUG/(1350): The Saved Contact is checked here
 01-01 06:25:37.464: DEBUG/(1350): The Saved Contact is checked here
 01-01 06:25:37.472: DEBUG/(1350): The Saved Contact is checked here
 01-01 06:25:39.081: DEBUG/(1350): The INPUT TYPE OF MDIGITS onPause 1
 01-01 06:25:39.097: WARN/InputManagerService(1082): Ignoring hideInputMethod of token: null
 01-01 06:25:39.222: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1404): GC freed 70 objects / 5424 bytes in 143ms
 01-01 06:25:39.573: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1350): GC freed 41355 objects / 1657488 bytes in 214ms
 01-01 06:25:39.589: DEBUG/(1350): The Saved Contact is checked here
 01-01 06:25:39.589: INFO/dalvikvm(1350): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
 01-01 06:25:39.589: INFO/dalvikvm(1350): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@45c8b2b0 on calls that has not been deactivated or closed
 01-01 06:25:39.589: INFO/dalvikvm(1350):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
 01-01 06:25:39.589: INFO/dalvikvm(1350):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
 01-01 06:25:39.620: WARN/IInputConnectionWrapper(1350): finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
 01-01 06:25:39.698: INFO/DEBUG(1008): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
 01-01 06:25:39.698: INFO/DEBUG(1008): Build fingerprint: 'zoom/ldp1/ldp1/ldp1:Donut/Donut/eng.vishal.20091203.130315:eng/test-keys'
 01-01 06:25:39.698: INFO/DEBUG(1008): pid: 1350, tid: 1355  >>> android.process.acore <<<
 01-01 06:25:39.698: INFO/DEBUG(1008): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr 00000004
 01-01 06:25:39.698: INFO/DEBUG(1008):  r0 00000004  r1 40023778  r2 00000004  r3 ad32d629
 01-01 06:25:39.698: INFO/DEBUG(1008):  r4 00000000  r5 00000000  r6 ad34e495  r7 4203afb8
 01-01 06:25:39.698: INFO/DEBUG(1008):  r8 100ffd00  r9 4203afb0  10 4203afa0  fp 00000001
 01-01 06:25:39.698: INFO/DEBUG(1008):  ip ad372c80  sp 100ffce8  lr ad32d633  pc afb04408  cpsr 00000010
 01-01 06:25:39.776: INFO/DEBUG(1008):          #00  pc 00004408  /system/lib/libcutils.so
 01-01 06:25:39.784: INFO/DEBUG(1008):          #01  lr ad32d633  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
 01-01 06:25:39.784: INFO/DEBUG(1008): stack:
 01-01 06:25:39.784: INFO/DEBUG(1008):     100ffca8  45ba1410  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/2 (deleted)
 01-01 06:25:39.784: INFO/DEBUG(1008):     100ffcac  ad371820  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
 01-01 06:25:39.784: INFO/DEBUG(1008):     100ffcb0  45ba1410  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/2 (deleted)
 01-01 06:25:39.784: INFO/DEBUG(1008):     100ffcb4  afd00949  /system/lib/libstdc++.so
 01-01 06:25:39.784: INFO/DEBUG(1008):     100ffcb8  0028c820  [heap]
 01-01 06:25:39.784: INFO/DEBUG(1008):     100ffcbc  43079f5c  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@framework.jar@classes.dex
 01-01 06:25:39.784: INFO/DEBUG(1008):     100ffcc0  00000001  
 01-01 06:25:39.784: INFO/DEBUG(1008):     100ffcc4  43079f5c  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@framework.jar@classes.dex
 01-01 06:25:39.784: INFO/DEBUG(1008):     100ffcc8  00000001  
 01-01 06:25:39.784: INFO/DEBUG(1008):     100ffccc  a9d222bf  /system/lib/libutils.so
 01-01 06:25:39.784: INFO/DEBUG(1008):     100ffcd0  0000a000  [heap]
 01-01 06:25:39.784: INFO/DEBUG(1008):     100ffcd4  420f30b8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
 01-01 06:25:39.784: INFO/DEBUG(1008):     100ffcd8  100ffd30  
 01-01 06:25:39.784: INFO/DEBUG(1008):     100ffcdc  0000000d  
 01-01 06:25:39.792: INFO/DEBUG(1008):     100ffce0  df002777  
 01-01 06:25:39.792: INFO/DEBUG(1008):     100ffce4  e3a070ad  
 01-01 06:25:39.800: INFO/DEBUG(1008): #00 100ffce8  00000000  
 01-01 06:25:39.800: INFO/DEBUG(1008):     100ffcec  ad32d633  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
 01-01 06:25:39.800: INFO/DEBUG(1008):     100ffcf0  100ffd20  
 01-01 06:25:39.800: INFO/DEBUG(1008):     100ffcf4  ad34e4a5  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
 01-01 06:25:39.800: INFO/DEBUG(1008):     100ffcf8  40023778  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/zygote/0 (deleted)
 01-01 06:25:39.800: INFO/DEBUG(1008):     100ffcfc  ad00e438  /system/lib/libdvm.so
 01-01 06:25:39.800: INFO/DEBUG(1008):     100ffd00  420f30b8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
 01-01 06:25:39.800: INFO/DEBUG(1008):     100ffd04  0010e8a0  [heap]
 01-01 06:25:39.800: INFO/DEBUG(1008):     100ffd08  ad34e495  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
 01-01 06:25:39.808: INFO/DEBUG(1008):     100ffd0c  40023778  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/zygote/0 (deleted)
 01-01 06:25:39.808: INFO/DEBUG(1008):     100ffd10  00001071  
 01-01 06:25:39.808: INFO/DEBUG(1008):     100ffd14  0010e8a0  [heap]
 01-01 06:25:39.808: INFO/DEBUG(1008):     100ffd18  100ffd20  
 01-01 06:25:39.808: INFO/DEBUG(1008):     100ffd1c  ad040b11  /system/lib/libdvm.so
 01-01 06:25:39.808: INFO/DEBUG(1008):     100ffd20  4203afb0  
 01-01 06:25:39.808: INFO/DEBUG(1008):     100ffd24  43108546  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@framework.jar@classes.dex
 01-01 06:25:39.808: INFO/DEBUG(1008):     100ffd28  ad34e495  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
 01-01 06:25:39.808: INFO/DEBUG(1008):     100ffd2c  100ffd98  
 01-01 06:25:39.823: DEBUG/(1350): The Saved Contact is checked here
 01-01 06:25:39.855: DEBUG/(1350): The Saved Contact is checked here
 01-01 06:25:40.667: INFO/DEBUG(1008): debuggerd committing suicide to free the zombie!
 01-01 06:25:40.667: INFO/DEBUG(1505): debuggerd: Dec  3 2009 13:23:48
 01-01 06:25:40.675: DEBUG/Zygote(1010): Process 1350 terminated by signal (11)
 01-01 06:25:40.683: INFO/ActivityManager(1082): Process android.process.acore (pid 1350) has died.
 01-01 06:25:40.698: INFO/WindowManager(1082): WIN DEATH: Window{45afa370 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher.Launcher paused=false}
 01-01 06:25:40.698: INFO/WindowManager(1082): WIN DEATH: Window{45b93050 com.android.contacts/com.android.contacts.DialtactsActivity paused=false}
 01-01 06:25:40.698: INFO/WindowManager(1082): WINDOW DIED during motion dispatch: Window{45b93050 com.android.contacts/com.android.contacts.DialtactsActivity paused=false}
 01-01 06:25:40.714: WARN/WindowManager(1082): Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@45a64c98 does not exist
 01-01 06:25:40.714: WARN/WindowManager(1082): java.lang.RuntimeException
 01-01 06:25:40.714: WARN/WindowManager(1082):     at com.android.server.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:7756)
 01-01 06:25:40.714: WARN/WindowManager(1082):     at com.android.server.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:7748)
 01-01 06:25:40.714: WARN/WindowManager(1082):     at com.android.server.WindowManagerService.removeWindow(WindowManagerService.java:1348)
 01-01 06:25:40.714: WARN/WindowManager(1082):     at com.android.server.WindowManagerService.dispatchPointer(WindowManagerService.java:4067)
 01-01 06:25:40.714: WARN/WindowManager(1082):     at com.android.server.WindowManagerService.access$1200(WindowManagerService.java:127)
 01-01 06:25:40.714: WARN/WindowManager(1082):     at com.android.server.WindowManagerService$InputDispatcherThread.process(WindowManagerService.java:5345)
 01-01 06:25:40.714: WARN/WindowManager(1082):     at com.android.server.WindowManagerService$InputDispatcherThread.run(WindowManagerService.java:5253)
 01-01 06:25:40.800: INFO/jdwp(1506): received file descriptor 13 from ADB
 01-01 06:25:40.800: INFO/jdwp(1506): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
 01-01 06:25:40.800: INFO/jdwp(1506): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
 01-01 06:25:40.808: INFO/ActivityManager(1082): Start proc android.process.acore for activity com.android.launcher/.Launcher: pid=1506 uid=10001 gids={3003, 1015}
 01-01 06:25:40.816: DEBUG/ddm-heap(1506): Got feature list request
 01-01 06:25:40.862: WARN/Process(1082): Unable to open /proc/1350/status
 01-01 06:25:40.940: WARN/UsageStats(1082): Unexpected resume of com.android.launcher while already resumed in com.android.contacts
 01-01 06:25:40.972: INFO/ActivityThread(1506): Publishing provider user_dictionary: com.android.providers.userdictionary.UserDictionaryProvider
 01-01 06:25:41.003: INFO/ActivityThread(1506): Publishing provider applications: com.android.providers.applications.ApplicationsProvider
 01-01 06:25:41.050: INFO/ActivityThread(1506): Publishing provider com.android.globalsearch.SuggestionProvider: com.android.globalsearch.SuggestionProvider
 01-01 06:25:41.120: INFO/ActivityThread(1506): Publishing provider com.android.googlesearch.SuggestionProvider: com.android.googlesearch.SuggestionProvider
 01-01 06:25:41.144: INFO/ActivityThread(1506): Publishing provider com.android.websearch.Suggest: com.android.websearch.SuggestionProvider
 01-01 06:25:41.159: INFO/ActivityThread(1506): Publishing provider com.android.globalsearch.stats: com.android.globalsearch.StatsProvider
 01-01 06:25:41.159: INFO/ActivityThread(1506): Publishing provider contacts;call_log: com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider
 01-01 06:25:41.253: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1506): GC freed 3627 objects / 260784 bytes in 57ms
 01-01 06:25:41.253: WARN/ActivityManager(1082): Unable to start service Intent { act=android.accounts.IAccountsService cmp=com.google.android.googleapps/.GoogleLoginService }: not found
 01-01 06:25:41.261: WARN/AccountMonitor(1506): Couldn't connect to Intent { act=android.accounts.IAccountsService cmp=com.google.android.googleapps/.GoogleLoginService } (Missing service?)
 01-01 06:25:41.261: INFO/ActivityThread(1506): Publishing provider com.android.launcher.settings: com.android.launcher.LauncherProvider
```

IF any one has any idea let me know :(

Answer (score 0):

See this issue about "[Quite a few errors related to the lack of Google components in the
open-source tree.](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=998)"

Comment: Thanks for responding David, but I'm not getting a clue as to how is this related to the non availability of some 'things' from google source??